# How to organize multiple levels of class inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, code-organization, gdscript

Note about the language: it has classes that can inherit one another. If a descendant class has a function with the same name as a function in an ancestor class, the function in the ancestor class will not run at all for instances of the descendant.

Problem: I want to know what's the best way to create functions that expand on the behaviours of ancestor classes without overriding any of them.

Pseudocode of what I'm doing right now:

```
class_name Animal

func _doSomething():
  #do something common to "Animal"
  _doSomething_descendantOfAnimal()

func _doSomething_descendantOfAnimal():
  #no behaviour here, since it will be overridden by descendants
```

Code for another class extending "Animal"

```
class_name Feline
extends Animal

func _doSomething_descendantOfAnimal():
  #behaviour common to "Feline"
  _doSomething_descendantOfFeline()
 
func _doSomething_descendantOfFeline():
  #no behaviour here
```

Code for another class extending "Feline"

```
class_name HouseCat
extends Feline

func _doSomething_descendantOfFeline():
  #behaviour specific to "HouseCat"
```

This organization means that when I call `_doSomething()` on a `HouseCat` instance, the behaviours common to `Animal` and `Feline` will run **in addition** to any specific behaviour of `HouseCat` itself. Nevertheless, I feel like there is a cleaner, more efficient way to do things. One that doesn't require me to add a blank function (like `_doSomething_descendantOfFeline()`) to each class that can possibly be extended by another, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would usually do is the following: have the function override the function of parent class, with code that calls the function of parent class. GDScript syntax for it is `.`. *For GDScript 2.0 in Godot 4, it is `super.`.*

Example from the official documentation for Godot 4.1:

```
func some_func(x):
    super(x) # Calls the same function on the parent class.
```

See [GDScript basics: class inheritance (latest stable version)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#inheritance).

Godot 3.6 example:

```
func some_func(x):
    .some_func(x) # Calls the same function on the parent class.
```

See [GDScript basics: class inheritance (Godot 3.6)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.6/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#inheritance).